# 'Invalid-channel' error when using REST API 'chat.postMessage'

Tags: rocket.chat

I’m getting an ‘invalid-channel’ error when using the Rocket.Chat API 'chat.postMessage' command

my code is shown below, can anyone see what i’m doing wrong here? thanks!

I’ve tried different formats for the channel name in the code (which incidentally is a public one, its also the initial channel created and has an id of GENERAL)

```
"GENERAL"
"@GENERAL"
"#GENERAL"
“My_Chat_Room”
“@My_Chat_Room”
“#My_Chat_Room”
```

all the above with and without a space after the '#' or '@', and all of these in lowercase

```
    function postMsg(){
var request = require(‘request’);

var url = ‘https://my.rocketchat.server/api/v1/login/’;
var user = ‘Test_User’;
var pass = ‘DFSdnwe89eq339’;

// Save these for future requests
var userId;
var authToken;

request.post(
{
uri: url,
form: { username: user, password: pass }
},
function(err, httpResponse, body) {
if (err) {
return console.error(‘Login failed:’, err);
}
var json = JSON.parse(body);
authToken = json.data.authToken;
userId = json.data.userId;
console.log(‘Login successful!:’ + “\n” + "User ID: " + userId + “\n” + "Auth Token: " + authToken);

  var postMsgUrl = 'https://my.rocketchat.server/api/v1/chat.postMessage';

  request.post({
  uri: postMsgUrl, 
  headers: {
  'X-User-Id': userId,
  'X-Auth-Token': authToken
  },
  data: {
  "channel": "My_Chat_Room", 
  "text": "test message", 
  }
  }, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('post failed:', err, body);
    }

console.log('Server responded with:', httpResponse, body);
});
}
)}
```

The expected result is that the text specified in the request gets posted to the channel, however all i get is the 'invalid-channel' error

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell rocket that your request has a json payload.

Add this header: `"Content-type:application/json"`